# A string containing `<people.txt` does not render

Tags: bug, markdown-rendering

The Bash command  `sort  -k2,2 -k1,1 <people.txt` is not displayed properly.

[image]

`<people.txt` is not in the preview. This is not an issue on some other sites.

I can write the command as `sort  -k2,2 -k1,1 &lt;people.txt` to escape it.
Is that the right way to do it? May I call it a bug in Stack Overflow?

Comment: how many spaces is there before the word sort? did you try clearing the line, clicking the code formatting button (`{}`) and putting the line in again?

Comment: it is taking it as [html tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) since they are allowed in editor. You should escape it using backticks or  use the HTML entity &lt;.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the code button <kbd>{}</kbd> or give 4 spaces (markdown syntax) to display the bash snippet.

```
sort  -k2,2 -k1,1 <people.txt
```

As I mentioned in the comment, 
it is taking it as [html tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) since they are allowed in editor. You can escape it using **backticks** or use the HTML entity `&lt;`.

sort  -k2,2 -k1,1 `<`people.txt

or

sort  -k2,2 -k1,1 <people.txt